# Background image full height

Tags: html, css, image, background, height

So my problem is that if i scroll down the background image randomly dissapears at some point and starts showing background color. Here is a gif to explain https://gyazo.com/d2d742a1ff1225babe04faa0a597ada9

```
<body>
    <div class="taust">
    </div>
    <div class="randomcontent">
    <h1>random content</h1>
    </div>


    </body>

.taust{
    top:0;
      background-image: url(taust.jpg);
      background-repeat:repeat-x;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-position: left top;
    position:absolute;
      overflow:auto;
          z-index:-5;
    min-width:100%;
    height:100vh;
    margin:0;
}
.randomcontent{
    width:80%;
    height:2000px;
    right:0; left:0;
    margin:auto;
    border:solid 2px blue;
    background:red;
    text-align:center;

}
.randomcontent h1{
    font-size:100px;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to have a background image? Because if you are, you're using very poor code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also try using:

```
background-size: cover;
```

this will keep it static when scrolling.

Comment: This made it much better.

Answer (score 1):

This will produce the same output but with a cleaner look.

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
}

.taust{
    background: url(taust.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    background: blue; /* Delete this line when you paste this code */
}
.randomcontent{
    width:80%;
    height:2000px;
    margin:auto;
    border:solid 2px blue;
    background:red;
    text-align:center;
}
.randomcontent h1{
    font-size:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="taust">
 <div class="randomcontent">
 <h1>random content</h1>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: fixed;` instead of `position: absolute;`

Comment: A little more explanation would be helpful to future readers.